# Pandas how to select dateframe starting from the first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to build a tradelog P&L Calculator to calc profits on a daily basis.

and i dont want it to be in the frame so it won't mess up the data.

the results I am expecting of the function i am looking for is to remove the first 3 rows of TransactionSell and start from the first-row In TransactionBuy and remove the last row in TransactionBuy because if not then it will bee calculated as a loss.so i want to select until the last record of TransactionSell> 0

---

another way of explaining: 
I want to select the frame starting from 
the first occurrence where (TransactionBuy<0)
and until the last occurrence where(TransactionSell>0)
so I want everything between 
keep in mind that this frame number of rows or index may be different each time so not every time I would want to delete the first 3 rows maybe the first 6 rows based on the data I have

for your ref : [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JgzBmyRugpZ8a-yS2LZs6mvH5Fu2ezdU/view?usp=sharing)
CurrentOutput: notice(44,45,46 & 66)

```
                           time  TransactionBuy  TransactionSell       Added
     44 2020-03-03 17:59:02.910        0.000000        13.134000   13.134000
     45 2020-03-03 17:59:02.910        0.000000       495.470412  495.470412
     46 2020-03-03 17:59:02.910        0.000000         0.367416    0.367416
     47 2020-03-03 19:21:53.911     -339.399798         0.000000 -339.399798
     48 2020-03-03 19:21:53.912       -0.004492         0.000000   -0.004492
     49 2020-03-03 20:16:24.467        0.000000       147.008308  147.008308
     50 2020-03-03 20:16:24.467        0.000000        64.857600   64.857600
     51 2020-03-03 20:16:24.467        0.000000       128.706304  128.706304
     52 2020-03-03 22:37:40.707     -407.888854         0.000000 -407.888854
     53 2020-03-03 23:09:47.226        0.000000       411.694238  411.694238
     54 2020-03-04 07:19:06.956     -329.905914         0.000000 -329.905914
     55 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        36.782438   36.782438
     56 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        22.980837   22.980837
     57 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        38.059571   38.059571
     58 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        43.848657   43.848657
     59 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000       109.471160  109.471160
     60 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        69.434052   69.434052
     61 2020-03-05 09:25:20.725      -15.297384         0.000000  -15.297384
     62 2020-03-05 09:25:20.725     -134.850000         0.000000 -134.850000
     63 2020-03-05 09:25:20.725      -50.684721         0.000000  -50.684721
     64 2020-03-05 09:25:21.690     -676.801362         0.000000 -676.801362
     65 2020-03-05 10:19:20.014        0.000000       857.315706  857.315706
     66 2020-03-05 10:25:20.014       -100.000000       0.000000  -100.00000
```

WHAT I WANT IS :

```
                          time  TransactionBuy  TransactionSell       Added

     47 2020-03-03 19:21:53.911     -339.399798         0.000000 -339.399798
     48 2020-03-03 19:21:53.912       -0.004492         0.000000   -0.004492
     49 2020-03-03 20:16:24.467        0.000000       147.008308  147.008308
     50 2020-03-03 20:16:24.467        0.000000        64.857600   64.857600
     51 2020-03-03 20:16:24.467        0.000000       128.706304  128.706304
     52 2020-03-03 22:37:40.707     -407.888854         0.000000 -407.888854
     53 2020-03-03 23:09:47.226        0.000000       411.694238  411.694238
     54 2020-03-04 07:19:06.956     -329.905914         0.000000 -329.905914
     55 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        36.782438   36.782438
     56 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        22.980837   22.980837
     57 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        38.059571   38.059571
     58 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        43.848657   43.848657
     59 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000       109.471160  109.471160
     60 2020-03-04 07:39:48.064        0.000000        69.434052   69.434052
     61 2020-03-05 09:25:20.725      -15.297384         0.000000  -15.297384
     62 2020-03-05 09:25:20.725     -134.850000         0.000000 -134.850000
     63 2020-03-05 09:25:20.725      -50.684721         0.000000  -50.684721
     64 2020-03-05 09:25:21.690     -676.801362         0.000000 -676.801362
     65 2020-03-05 10:19:20.014        0.000000       857.315706  857.315706
```

Comment: Did you mean `TransactionBuy<0` or `abs(TransactionBuy)>0`?

Comment: sorry yes TransactionBuy<0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmad, i think this is what you're looking for: (expanding from @mrzo)

```
df.loc[(df['TransactionBuy'] < 0).idxmax():df.index[df['TransactionSell'] > 0][-1]]
```

Comment: another variant `df.loc[(df['TransactionBuy'] < 0).idxmax():df.where(df.TransactionSell > 0).last_valid_index()]`

Comment: I tried it and it returned the same data frame without deleting anything , the first one i tried, let me check the second // /    df = pd.read_csv('tradelogStack.csv')
df.loc[(df['TransactionBuy'] < 0).idxmax():df.index[df. TransactionSell > 0][-1]]
print(df)

Comment: are you using python3?

Comment: Done it works fine. I forgot to assign the df to a new view. MORE THAN THANK YOU

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as correct so people with the same question can reach it

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is already sorted by time:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
start = df.index[df.TransactionBuy < 0][0]
end = df.index[df.TransactionSell > 0][-1]
df.loc[start:end]
```

```
time  TransactionBuy  TransactionSell       Added
47 2020-03-03  19:21:53.911     -339.399798         0.000000 -339.399798
48 2020-03-03  19:21:53.912       -0.004492         0.000000   -0.004492
49 2020-03-03  20:16:24.467        0.000000       147.008308  147.008308
50 2020-03-03  20:16:24.467        0.000000        64.857600   64.857600
51 2020-03-03  20:16:24.467        0.000000       128.706304  128.706304
52 2020-03-03  22:37:40.707     -407.888854         0.000000 -407.888854
53 2020-03-03  23:09:47.226        0.000000       411.694238  411.694238
54 2020-03-04  07:19:06.956     -329.905914         0.000000 -329.905914
55 2020-03-04  07:39:48.064        0.000000        36.782438   36.782438
56 2020-03-04  07:39:48.064        0.000000        22.980837   22.980837
57 2020-03-04  07:39:48.064        0.000000        38.059571   38.059571
58 2020-03-04  07:39:48.064        0.000000        43.848657   43.848657
59 2020-03-04  07:39:48.064        0.000000       109.471160  109.471160
60 2020-03-04  07:39:48.064        0.000000        69.434052   69.434052
61 2020-03-05  09:25:20.725      -15.297384         0.000000  -15.297384
62 2020-03-05  09:25:20.725     -134.850000         0.000000 -134.850000
63 2020-03-05  09:25:20.725      -50.684721         0.000000  -50.684721
64 2020-03-05  09:25:21.690     -676.801362         0.000000 -676.801362
65 2020-03-05  10:19:20.014        0.000000       857.315706  857.315706
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i just tested it, it only removed row 66 and not the first 3 rows

Comment: How did you test it? I get the exact same results as in your question.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('tradelogStack.csv')
start = df.index[df.TransactionBuy < 0][0]
end = df.index[df.TransactionSell > 0][-1]
df.loc[start:end]
print(df)

Comment: You should do `print(df.loc[start:end])` or `new_df = df.loc[start:end]; print(new_df)` otherwise the changes are not visible.

Comment: works not forget to set a view, thank you very much.

Comment: If it works for you, just accept or upvote an answer.